# How do I create vertices that form square faces on a rectangle?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, faces

I need to do this so I can build terrain properly.

This is what I am trying to get square faces on:

[image]

I tried deleting everything but the corners and this happens:

[image]

And this is what I want, square faces:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps square faces is a better term.

Comment: In your case just dissolve edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm curious about how come you have to start from this topology?

In this particular case though, you could:

[image]

- Select a vertical edge, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Select Similar > Direction*
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> (*Select Inverse*)
- <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* the now selected edges

Comment: Thank you for the help! :)